# Writing to MongoDB without waiting for response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to write to a MongoDB using Mongoose and Node.js without waiting for the response. The typical way to write to MongoDB is either to use the callback syntax or use the await/async pattern. Both of these patterns don't execute the query unless you specify a call back or await the response.

Is there a way to write to MongoDB in a 'best-effort' fashion? I.e. just make the call, don't wait for the response, and if it succeeds great, and if not, no problem.

EDIT:

Code:

Async/await pattern:

```
const doc = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate('prod1', {$inc: {viewed: 1}});
console.log(doc);
```

Callback pattern

```
Product.findByIdAndUpdate('prod1', {$inc: {viewed: 1}, func(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc)
});
```

Both of these wait for the response.

Comment: add some code in question..!what have you tried?

Comment: I mean, like I said, I know how to do it with await/async or a callback. Do you want me to write standard queries using each syntax? Seems like it'd just be writing code to write code, without enhancing the meaning of the question.

Comment: I was asking code to suggest the way in existing code..!
and the answer is pretty simple..just put callback of function outside of mongo query or before the await query..!

Comment: No that would not work for anyone else reading this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the write using [w:0 write concern setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/). This will instruct MongoDB to do the write, but not waiting for feedback. For example:

```
  conn.db('test').collection('test').insertOne({'a': 1}, {'w': 0}, function(err, res) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log(res);
  })
```

The default write concern is `w:1` (wait for confirmation from the node you're connecting to). If you check the `res` output of the code above using `w:1`, it will show:

```
  ...
  insertedCount: 1,
  ...
```

In contrast, using `w:0` will show:

```
  ...
  insertedCount: undefined,
  ...
```

**Note:** although writes will return quickly with best-effort using this setting, this is essentially UDP for your writes. Use at your own risk.